# sql error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run this query but is not working. I am getting an error. How to fix?:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Jon Yang ' to data type int.

sql

```
use adventureworks 
go 

select si.CustomerID, 
'myField' = 
            CASE 
                 When (Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + LastName + ' ' + EmailPromotion   From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid ) is not null Then  
            Cast((Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + LastName  + ' ' + EmailPromotion From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid  ) As varchar) 
            Else '' 
            END 
from Sales.Individual si 
where si.CustomerID=11000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because of [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx): nvarchar will be converted to int.

It is either on `EmailPromotion` or `CustomerID` so decide which line you want below.
Also, no need to use an inline query.

```
select
    si.CustomerID, 
    'myField' = ISNULL(FirstName + ' ' + 
                       LastName  + ' ' + 
                       Cast(EmailPromotion AS nvarchar(100))
                       -- EmailPromotion ?
                       , '')
from
    Sales.Individual si 
    LEFT JOIN
    Person.Contact pc ON si.ContactID = pc.contactid
where
    si.CustomerID = N'11000'
    -- si.CustomerID = 11000 ?
```

TOP without ORDER BY is meaningless, so if you have multiple rows in `Person.Contact` for each row in `Sales.Individual` you'd need another construct...

Answer (score 0):

One of the fields you're adding must be of type int - could it be the "EmailPromotion" field?  In any case - that addition implies a conversion, but obviously you can't add a name to a number.  Instead, try this:

```
use adventureworks 
go 

select si.CustomerID, 
'myField' = 
            CASE 
                 When (Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + LastName + ' ' + cast(EmailPromotion   as nvarchar) From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid ) is not null Then  
            Cast((Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + LastName  + ' ' + cast(EmailPromotion   as nvarchar)  From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid  ) As varchar) 
            Else '' 
            END 
from Sales.Individual si 
where si.CustomerID=11000
```